# Plots.jl: How to play points and lines or two different series?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I want to plot `1:3` using points but `3:-1:1` using lines.

How do I achieve this with Plots.jl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plot one thing first and then use a new plot command with a bang to modify the previous plot.

```
scatter(1:3)
plot!(3:-1:1)
```